# Will vs would vs may

Tags: grammar, meaning

I would like to know the difference between the following sentences bcz its very confusing to me.

> 1) A person may say:
>
> Look at that bridge, it is so old that it **would** fall by next year.
>   Look at that bridge, it is so old that it **will** fall by next year.
>   Look at that bridge, it is so old that it **may** fall by next year.

I would like to know the sample context in which I can use them and why do we use would here as opposed to will if certain or may if not certain.

> 2) Who is at the door
>
> That **would** be my friend John
>   That **will** be my friend John
>   That **may** be my friend John

The same confusion

Comment: ***Would*** doesn't work in your context (there's nothing "conditional" about the context within which something *would* happen). But ***will*** asserts a definite prediction about the future, whereas ***may*** simply asserts the *possibility* of the prediction coming true.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [May vs can, could or would](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/70784/may-vs-can-could-or-would) Also [When to use “will” and “may” in a sentence](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/71715/when-to-use-will-and-may-in-a-sentence), [There would be/will be/might be](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/93694/there-would-be-will-be-might-be), and others.

Comment: You have now changed the question. Had I not checked it, I would not have seen it. "That would be John" is in response to: Who would that be?

Comment: Hello 

I would like to know why is the would used in the following paragraph,if certain we could have used 'will' and if not' may'

It is from the editorial section of a newspaper

India's ease of doing business

Harmonization of laws ,procedures and rates of taxes, will improve environment of compliance as all returns to be filled online ,input credits to be verified online reducing need to deal with different tax authorities .It would also discourage mere invoice shipping.

I would be really grateful .

Comment: @FumbleFingers linked qn doesn't have answers for this but a comment

Comment: @bholeshverma you should comment on the answers

Answer (score 1):

"Will fail" means it is going to happen. "May fail" means there is a possibility it will happen.

And *would happen* is not grammatical in your sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the knock at the door, the sentence "That would be my friend John" is an answer to the (unasked but potentially asked)question "Who might that be?". If the unasked question to which the speaker thinks they are responding was "Who is that?", the speaker could say either "That is ...John" or "That will be ..John". The latter suggesting that the speaker was expecting John to call.

A native speaker could use any of these without exciting comment.

As to your bridge, none of the sentences sound like something a native speaker would say. The "by next year" is spurious precision without rhetorical effect.

One might say "Look at that old bridge! It might collapse any minute." In saying that, the speaker is not really suggesting that they believe the bridge will in fact collapse within a few minutes, but that they think it looks so precarious that collapse is a possibility.